# Bug in .NET's DateTime.ToString("R") with UTC dates?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm based in the UK (GMT+1 time at the moment).

If I run this:

```
> DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R")  // Or...
> DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R")
"Mon, 06 Oct 2014 10:20:00 GMT"
```

Correct answer.
If I now run the same, without UTC DateTime conversion:

```
> DateTime.Now.ToString("R")
"Mon, 06 Oct 2014 11:20:00 GMT"
```

The time printed is correct, but the timezone is wrong. I would expect instead:

```
"Mon, 06 Oct 2014 11:20:00"  // Or..
"Mon, 06 Oct 2014 11:20:00 BST"
```

Question: **Is this behaviour by design? Can I get the same output as with the "R" format, but with the correct timezone indicator?**

Comment: "11:20 GMT" is *not* correct, assuming you did this 9 minutes ago. It's 11:20 BST, which is 10:20 GMT. The second output is *correct*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you're right. The question should be the other way around. Correcting...

Comment: It is worth clarifying that at the moment the UK is *not* GMT timezone as you've stated in the question. UK has two timezones, GMT and BST. GMT is the same as UTC but in the summer it is not correct to say that UK timezone is GMT.

Comment: @Mau: With the corrected question it seems obvious that the problem is that the people at MS who coded up the timezones didn't seemingly realise that we have different names for things. I wonder if you have the same problem with americans and others with separate summertimes or if this is unique to the UK...

Comment: @Chris: In most representations, the UK has one time zone (e.g. "Europe/London") which observes different UTC offsets and abbreviations at different times of the year. I'm unaware of a good name for "half a time zone" (such as BST) but I wouldn't call it a time zone. And no, I don't believe it's a "different names for things" issue at all - see my answer and the documentation.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I will take your word for that since I know you have put a lot more research into this for Noda. My personal usage is that GMT and BST are timezones that we swap between and that "Europe/London" is just a location used to identify the timezone used. I see what you mean having read the docs and the answer and it does seem like very stupid design. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely not a bug, it's the [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#RFC1123) behaviour:

> The custom format string is `"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'"`. When this standard format specifier is used, the formatting or parsing operation always uses the invariant culture.
>
> ...
>
> Although the RFC 1123 standard expresses a time as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), the formatting operation does not modify the value of the `DateTime` object that is being formatted. Therefore, you must convert the `DateTime` value to UTC by calling the `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` method before you perform the formatting operation. In contrast, `DateTimeOffset` values perform this conversion automatically; there is no need to call the `DateTimeOffset.ToUniversalTime` method before the formatting operation.

As I noted in a comment on the question, 10:20 GMT is correct, assuming that you ran the code shortly before asking the question: 11:20 GMT has not occurred yet.

So basically, when you follow the guidance in the documentation and call `ToUniversalTime`, it does the right thing. When you don't, it gives a misleading value - that's unfortunate, but part of the broken design of `DateTime` IMO.

You should consider at least using `DateTimeOffset`, or potentially using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project instead.

Comment: Thanks. We have been considering Noda Time for a while now, actually :)

Comment: @jon skeet It certainly looks like a bug from my perspective... is there a use case for this behaviour? Or is just not considered a bug, because it's documented?

Comment: @marvc1: I couldn't really comment on that. It would depend on which definition of "bug" you're using. I'd expect that at the very least it can't be changed now as that could break folks.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, I bet you're right as to why it hasn't been changed. I think it would only "break" the folks, who haven't called `dateTime.ToUniversalTime()` before calling `.ToString("R")`, who, like us, already have a bug anyway, which it would actually fix. If only we'd used Noda time from the start... 

Comment: @marvc1: It depends - if you parse something that you *know* is already in UTC, but leave it with a kind of "unspecified" for whatever reason, then calling `ToUniversalTime()` would break things - but the current behavior would work. I can see that being the case for some people.